# Recursively delete all files except a certain number in each directory

Tags: linux, bash, gnu

I have a large collection of files contained in directories for testing. I need to keep the directory structure for my application but want to thin out the files for faster testing. I want to limit the number of files a directory can have to 3. How can I do that in linux?

To clarify what I would like to accomplish, a solution in Python:

```py
import sys, os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    for index, file in enumerate(files):
        if index > int(sys.argv[2]) - 1: os.remove(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Usage:

```sh
python thinout.py /path/to/thin\ out/ <maximum_number_of_files_per_directory>
```

Example:

```sh
python thinout.py testing\ data 3
```

I found [a smiliar question about doing this for one directory, but not recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447326/how-to-delete-all-files-except-the-latest-three-in-a-folder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this in bash:

```
for dir in `find . -type d`; pushd $dir; rm `ls | awk 'NR>3'`; popd; done;
```

Or this version might be better:

```
for dir in `find . -type d`; pushd $dir; rm `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | tail -n +3`; popd; done;
```

Of course - just randomly deleting all but the first 3 files in the directory  is always a little risky. Buyer beware...

By the way, I did not test this myself. Just typed in what came to mind. You'll likely have to tweak it a little to get it to work right. Again, buyer beware.

Comment: Don't you need a "do " after the first semi-colon?

Comment: As @Perleone implies, this version won't work with directory names that need escaping (e.g., names with embedded spaces).

Answer (score 0):

This quite lengthy sequence will work with files containing spaces etc., and just leave the first three alphabetically sorted files in each subdir.

**EDIT:** applied [mklement](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement)'s improvement to cope with directories that need escaping.

```
find /var/testfiles/ -type d -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' subdir; \
do cd "$subdir"; find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | \
sort --zero-terminated | tr '\0' '\n' | tail -n+4 | tr '\n' '\0' | \
xargs --null --no-run-if-empty rm ; cd "$OLDPWD" ; done
```

Since my version of tail doesn't support a `--zero` or `--null` flag for line terminators, I had to work around that with `tr`. Suggestions for improvements are welcome.

Comment: Your directory loop won't work with directory names that need escaping. Use something like `find /var/testfiles/ -type d -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' subdir; do cd "$subdir"; ...`; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: @mklement I can not get the command to run with your modification. Could you perhaps make an edit or post your version as an individual answer?

Comment: @Perlene Your answer does not work for me. The cause seems to be whitespaces in the path.

Comment: @bngtlrs I've amended my answer, does the new version work for you?

Comment: @bngtlrs @Perleone's revised version looks OK. If you don't have to deal with filenames with embedded `\n` chars. (which is rare), here's a more concise version: `find "/var/testfiles" -type d | while read -r subdir; do (find "$subdir" -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort | tail -n +4 | while read -r f; do rm "$f"; done); done`. An added advantage of this version is that it can deal with a large number of files to delete, whereas the `xargs`-based version could exceed the max. length of a single command line.