# Delete all files except the latest 10 in subdirectories

Tags: linux, file, find, delete-file, subdirectory

I have some BackUp-Files from machines which store their Backup in different folders. Additionally the files are not created at the same time (Machine 1: every sunday, Machine 2: every first monday of the month, etc.).

I need to keep the latest 10 files in each folder and delete all the others. Because of the different backup-intervals I can't just delete all files older than x days.

The folder-structure is like this:

```
./<SystemType>/<FQDN_Machine1>/backup_2015_09_08_02_00_00.zip
./<SystemType>/<FQDN_Machine2>/backup_2015_09_01_14_00_00.zip
```

Comment: Hint: use `ls -t` piped to `head` or `tail`.

Answer (score 0):

```
IFS='
'
for i in dir/*; do
    ls -d1t $i/* | head -n-10
done | xargs rm
```

List all subdirs excluding latest ten and send it by `xargs` to `rm`.

Comment: Ok... I'm a linux noob :P when I write this into a bash-file ("filename.sh") and try to run, it states "find: paths must precede expression: %T@ %p\n"...

Comment: Ah yes... I was some kind of stupid, sorry for that. But when I execute the find command I also get the latest files which should not be found.

Maybe it is easier to find the latest 10 files in each subdirectory and then reverse that command...

Comment: Are you sure? `head -n-10` prints all except last ten.

Comment: It's been a while, but I'm not any step further... First I need to get all Subdirs and then all files except the latest 10 of each Subdir.

I've tried to use a bash with variables ("find -type d" into VAR1 and "find $(VAR1) -type f | head -n -10"), but this wasn't successful... :(

Comment: Oh, I totally misunderstood your question. I though you want to save ten files in total. Then it is somewhat easier.

Answer (score -1):

This is my solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat find ./ -type f | while IFS= read -r line
do
  find "$line" -type f | head -n -10 | while read file
  do
    rm -f "$file"
  done
done
```

Comment: I tried this but got the error below:
cat: invalid option -- y
Try `cat --help' for more information.

Comment: I've used this answer instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447326/how-to-delete-all-files-except-the-latest-three-in-a-folder