# bash file cron job has issue when new file arrives at vendor

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron, delete-file

I have changed this post down to just what I think the main problem is..

There is a need to leave the two latest 
[how to delete all files except the latest three in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447326/how-to-delete-all-files-except-the-latest-three-in-a-folder)

```
ls -t1 /home/jdoe/checks/downloads/*.md5 | head -n +2 | xargs rm -r
```

This removes the oldest files..

And to test:

```
ls -t1 /home/jdoe/checks/downloads/*.md5 | head -n +2
```

We really want to leave the two (2) newest files:

```
ls -t1 /home/jdoe/checks/downloads/*.md5 | tail -n +2 | xargs rm -r
```

This does not seem to work..

And to test:

```
ls -t1 /home/jdoe/checks/downloads/*.md5 | tail -n +2
```

Thanks!

Comment: I can't find a Q, interesting as your back-story is ;-) Maybe you want to highlight something like 'Why is X happening' OR 'How do we do Y' at the top, then we can read the backstory if needed. Actually, you should probably re-read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve` and whittle the above down to just the current issue. Good Luck!

Comment: @shellter I have changed the formatting of the question to be what I think the main problem is at this point.

Comment: arg! you wrote "leave the two latest how to delete all files except the latest three in a folder". Disregarding two or three, you want to be able to leave the N newest files in a directory, and delete all others?

Comment: @shellter I apologize for confusing question, but yes I want to leave the two (2) newest files.

Comment: ok, no worries. I have something else, I'll be back in a little while (less than 1 hr I think). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get some assistance from one of my co-workers and this appears to be what we need.

```
   ls -1tr /home/jdoe/checks/downloads/*.md5 | head -n -2 | while read f; do
     #rm -f "$f"
     print "file to delete is $f"
   done
```